# What is a 1-flowered raceme?

Tags: botany, plant-anatomy, flowers, morphology

[PlantNET](http://plantnet.rbgsyd.nsw.gov.au/cgi-bin/NSWfl.pl?page=nswfl&lvl=sp&name=Daviesia~acicularis) describes the inflorescences of *Daviesia acicularis* as:

> Racemes reduced to 1 flower

How is a 1-flowered raceme different from a single flower?